# validate and submit form when enter is pressed in input(textbox) field but does not select history when enter pressed

Tags: php, javascript

similar to how we have  onfocus and onclick on input tags I am using the below method( if the method is wrong please let me know what would be the proper method ) for submitting a form when someone presses enter on a textbox in a field in a form

Example when someone writes the password in the password field and presses enter (when the cursor is on the password field) the form should submit.

I even have a submit button but I want the same thing to happen when text has enter pressed when submit is clicked

I am using this right now

```
onkeypress='if (event.keyCode == 13) { validate(); }'
```

for my textbox fields

the issue over here is that when the history of my text box shows below my text box and I select it by pressing enter it does not take the value first in my text box. It straight away validates the value in the text box

Example:
I have typed abcin my email textbox, I get abc@xyz.com below my text box showing that I had typed that earlier, not when I do down by pressing the down arrow and pressing enter it does not take abc@xyz.com in my text box but straight away runs validate() anhd gives me an error as wrong email format.

I believe it should first take my old value in the text box and then run the validate function

I am using codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to have understood your question,
maybe you need a code like this:

```
function submitMe(event) {
    if (window.event.keyCode == 13)
    {
        document.myForm.submit();
    }
}
```

Then in your HTML:

```
 <input type="input" ... onKeyPress="submitMe(event)"  value="">
```

or you can use `autocomplete="off"` instead of `value=""`

```
 <input type="input" ... onKeyPress="submitMe(event)"  autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: trying to use the above I am getting this error window.event is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Did you try method: onsumbit:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="validate()">...
```